# Why NetworkManager doesn't handle more than one 3g Dongle

Tags: network-manager, 20.04, mobile-broadband

on Ubuntu 20.04 NetworkManager won't manage multiple dongles at once.

I can connect to the internet with dongle A, and then disconnect it and connect with dongle B, but when both are plugged just one or none connects successfully.

Is that a know issue?

**EDIT1:**
I can now connect both the dongles mannually after:

- in nm-connection-editor disabling "automatic connection"
- enabling (in the above editor, ipv4, route pannel) "ignore auto obtained routes", "use this connection only for resources on it's network"

Since I have different card with different APN's I suppose NM doesn't know wich config to use ( `/etc/NetwokManager/system-connections/` )

I tried editing the config files in the above directory and adding the filter `device-id=***` ... didn't work

Searching the internet I found out that there's also a `sim-id` filter that can be used in the config files of NetworkManager, which identifies the sim card uniquely. It may solve the problem but I don't know how to obtain that value and if it's supported anymore.

Anyway if my theory is correct I'll just get two identical sim cards and even if  NM sends an APN config that was supposed to other device it should work anyway. I'll inform you if it does.

EDIT 2:
Now I have identical sim cards, still NM messes up... What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. When you have a full solution. Please write an answer to your own question and accept your answer as correct. That will help others.

Comment: You might find it easier to abandon network-manager and use plain netplan with systemd-networkd. Though I don't have experience with your particular problem I find netplan's configuration easier to deal with. Not a popular view but it works for some of us.

Comment: Please @StephenBoston, give me a hint on how to do that

Comment: Take a look through here https://netplan.io/examples. You can find these examples as templates in `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples` and fairly complete documentation in `/usr/share/doc/netplan/netplan.html`